# How to Get location of a button and make Textview appear in the Center of button with Onclick

Tags: android, button, textview, location, onclicklistener

I am a beginner and I believe it is relatively simple answer

I have a button randomly appearing in the screen. When I click the button I want to get its location and make textView visible center of the button.

```
   btnScale.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.startAnimation(animScale);
            btnScale.setClickable(false);

            int x = v.getLeft();
            int y = v.getTop();     

              if(txtView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                  txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

              }else{
                  txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  txtView.setX(x);
                  txtView.setY(y);
              }   

        }});
```

```
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip" 
    android:layout_centerVertical= "true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal= "true"
    android:background="@drawable/black_round_button"   
    />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/count"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:text="Appear"
      />
```

This is what I tried so far.

As it can be seen I use getLeft(), getTop() methods to get location of button.  However I cannot use it on setX, setY methods. It gives meaningless error.

Is there another way to do that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set a text to the button when it is clicked instead of using a TextView.

In your `onClick()` method write:

```
btnScale.setText("Appear");
```

Also, because your button's background is black, don't forget to add this line to your Button tag (xml):

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Hope it will help!